# Filter time series data based on a condition R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

I have a time series data which looks as below.

```
                         keyword             byMonth        n_views
business tax preparation software           Dec-2016              5
    corporate income tax solution           Nov-2016              3
    corporate income tax solution           Mar-2017              2
          corporate tax provision           Dec-2016              5
          corporate tax provision           Oct-2016              1
                  data collection           Mar-2017             39
                  data collection           May-2017             26
                  data collection           Apr-2017             22
                  data collection           Feb-2017             15
                  data collection           Jan-2017             15
                  data collection           Nov-2016             13
                  data collection           Dec-2016              7
                  data collection           Oct-2016              6
```

I want to select only those `keywords` that are throughout Oct-2016 to May-2017 using dplyr or any other convenient method. So in this case, only observations associated with `Keyword: data collection` should be the output. I am having a hard time figuring this out. Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: Row 5 is also `Oct-2016`, will `corporate tax provision` also be included?

Comment: No, only the keywords that exist from Oct-2016 to May-2017 throughout. Not just in few months. So, the output will only have `data collection`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use functions from `dplyr` and `tidyr`. The keyword in `dt2` are the cases with complete month coverage.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  # Spread the data frame
  spread(byMonth, n_views) %>%
  # Filter rows without any NA
  filter(rowSums(!is.na(.)) == ncol(.))
```

#### Update: Convert the data frame back to the original format

If the original format is needed, we can use `gather` to convert it back.

```
dt3 <- dt2 %>%
  gather(byMonth, n_views, -keyword)
```

#### Data Preparation

```
dt <- read.table(text = "                        keyword             byMonth        n_views
'business tax preparation software'           'Dec-2016'              5
               'corporate income tax solution'           'Nov-2016'              3
               'corporate income tax solution'           'Mar-2017'              2
               'corporate tax provision'           'Dec-2016'              5
               'corporate tax provision'           'Oct-2016'              1
               'data collection'           'Mar-2017'             39
               'data collection'           'May-2017'             26
               'data collection'           'Apr-2017'             22
               'data collection'           'Feb-2017'             15
               'data collection'           'Jan-2017'             15
               'data collection'           'Nov-2016'             13
               'data collection'           'Dec-2016'              7
               'data collection'           'Oct-2016'              6",
               header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I'm deleting my answer, as this seems to do what the asker actually wants.

Comment: Good idea, but I am using the output to plot a area chart and using the `byMonth` for x-axis. So this won't help. :(

Comment: @KrishnangKDalal Please see my update. We can conver the format back once the filtering is completed.

Comment: Cheers! Thanks a lot :)